# How can I add a "clicked" condition in knockout.js css-binding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

The documentation of css-binding in knockout.js provides an example as follows:

```
<div data-bind="css: { profitWarning: currentProfit() < 0 }">
   Profit Information
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   var viewModel = {
    currentProfit: ko.observable(150000) // Positive value, so initially we don't apply the "profitWarning" class
};
   viewModel.currentProfit(-50); // Causes the "profitWarning" class to be applied
</script>
```

It seems like this example applies the "profitWarning" currentProfit is negative. I want to change this a bit, and apply this class when the div is clicked. How can I apply the "clicked" condition to this example? Also, I want to make multiple divs and apply the style only one at a time (apply the style when a div is clicked and remove it when another div is clicked)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use click binding.

> The `click` binding adds an event handler so that your chosen JavaScript function will be invoked when the associated DOM element is clicked. This is most commonly used with elements like button, input, and a, but actually works with any visible DOM elemen

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Here is an example:

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
  self.className = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return self.isSelected()? "SelectedClass" : "NotSelectedClass";
  }, self);
  self.change = function() {
    self.isSelected(!self.isSelected());
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="text: className"></div> <br/>
<div data-bind="css: className">Inspect this Div</div> <br/>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: change" value="Toggle" />
```

For your second question, you can provide couple of boolean for each of the div to check which one is clicked, set the one clicked by user to true then set the rest to false.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one more question. Is it possible to change the color of the text when clicked and change back to its original color when another text is clicked just by using css-binding? (not click-binding)

Comment: Both must be used, click binding must be used to trigger the click event and css binding must be used to change the css className accordingly. You can't use only css as you won't be able to trigger the click event.